# How to send response form Axios dispatch to class component in reactjs? ( for react-pdf )

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

Im using React-PDF to generate a PDF, i want the pdf data from the response of a post request to an API which is in `mapDispatchToProps`. My code is

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    onSave: (data) => {
      Agent.API.add(data)
        .then((response) => {
          dispatch({ type: "SAVE" });
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          console.log(err);
        });
    },
}
```

and my function to generate PDF looks like

```
class Component extends React.Component {

generatePdfDocument = async (documentData) => {
    this.props.onSave(documentData)
    const blob = await pdf(<InvoiceTemplate data={dataFromRequest} />).toBlob();
    saveAs(blob, "test.pdf");
  };

  render() {
       return  <Button onClick={() => this.generatePdfDocument(data)} </Button>
  }
}
```

In `generatePdfDocument`, I call the function where the request takes place and then I want to pass the response from the same to `<Template>` as props. How do I do that?
PS - documentData is from the redux store.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want the result of this request `Agent.API.add(data)` to be passed to your `<InvoiceTemplate/>` component.

You need to either store the request response in your redux store or return it from your onSave function.

**Returning from the onSave function:**

```
onSave: (data) => {
      return Agent.API.add(data)
        .then((response) => {
          dispatch({ type: "SAVE" });
          return response; 
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          console.log(err);
        });
    },
```

Then pass this data to your component

```
generatePdfDocument = async (documentData) => {
    const dataFromRequest = await this.props.onSave(documentData)
    const blob = await pdf(<InvoiceTemplate data={dataFromRequest} />).toBlob();
    ...
}
```

**Using redux store**

1. Use a reducer to save response in store
2. Map state to props https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/connect-mapstate

Full tutorial here: https://react-redux.js.org/introduction/basic-tutorial